# How to Set Default seleted item in Select Options Binding while also passing Selected Value to other View Models?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am attempting to do two things:

1. Dynamically set the default value in a `Select Options Binding` (Select list) based on what is entered by a user or argument passed to the Selected Country `Observable`.
2. Access or pass the selected value to other view models so that other pages are rendered as the value changes.

In this example code, I have there are 3 `View Models`: A through C, and each view model gets `JSON` formatted data from a web services and needs the Selected Country.

**The problem:** I am unable to set a default Select Option dynamically while also passing or accessing the `Selected Value` so that the other view models are firing as the user changes the selection.

How do I pass an argument as default to the Selected Country while also allowing the Selected Country to other view models?

*View Model A:*

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout'], function($, ko){
    var self = this;
    self.CountryData = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SelectedCountry = ko.observable('USA');

    $.getJSON( 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all' )
        .done(function( data ) {
            self.CountryData(data);
        })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            alert( "Request Failed: " + err );
        });

   return function viewModelA() {
           self.Countries = ko.computed(function () {
                return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.CountryData(),
                    function (data) {
                        return {
                            Name: data.name + ' ' + data.capital,
                            value: data.alpha3Code
                        }
                    })
            });
      return {
          SelectedCountry: ko.computed(function () {
              return self.SelectedCountry();
          })
      }
    };
});
```

*View Model B:*

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout'], function($, ko){
    var self = this;
    self.CountryData = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.getJSON( 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/aruba?fullText=true' )
        .done(function( data ) {
            self.CountryData(data);
        })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            alert( "Request Failed: " + err );
        });

    return function viewModelB(viewModelA) {
        self.Location = ko.computed(function() {
            if (viewModelA.SelectedCountry()) {
                var match = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.CountryData(), function (item) {
                    return item.alpha3Code === viewModelA.SelectedCountry();
                })[0];
                if (match) {
                    return match.name;
                }
            }
       })
    }
});
```

*View Model C:*

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout'], function($, ko){
    var self = this;
    self.CountryData = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.getJSON( 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/capital/tallinn' )
        .done(function( data ) {
            self.CountryData(data);
        })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            alert( "Request Failed: " + err );
        });

    return function viewModelC(viewModelA) {
        self.Population = ko.computed(function() {
            if (viewModelA.SelectedCountry()) {
                var match = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.CountryData(), function (item) {
                    return item.alpha3Code === viewModelA.SelectedCountry();
                })[0];
                if (match) {
                    return match.population;
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Require Main:

```
require(['knockout', 'jquery', 'viewModelA', 'viewModelB', 'viewModelC'],
function (ko, $, viewModelA, viewModelB, viewModelC) {

    var vma = new viewModelA();
    var vmb = new viewModelB(vma);
    var vmc = new viewModelC(vma);

    ko.applyBindings(vma, document.getElementById('country'));
    ko.applyBindings(vmb, document.getElementById('location'));
    ko.applyBindings(vmc, document.getElementById('population'));

});
```

*HTML*

```
<select id="country" data-bind="options: Countries, optionsText: 'Name',
optionsValue: 'value', valueAllowUnset: true, value: SelectedCountry"></select>

<p id="location">Welcome! You are from: <span data-bind="text: Location"></span></p>

<p id="population">The population is: <span data-bind="text: Population"></span></p>
```

Comment: What is the `this` that you're setting `self` to in the anonymous require blocks? Shouldn't `self` be set to `this` inside the viewmodel constructors?

Comment: Not necessarily, I am only returning one view model (function) per definition. So Self represents the entire module.

Comment: You might check what `this` actually is. It's likely `window`, in which case you're making globals.